# Nested IF statement in function not working

Tags: javascript, html

in my function check(); The first IF Statement checks the contract Type, then within that if I have another nested IF statement that needs to to check if the checkbox has been checked or not.
This secondary nested IF statement is not working ... I have entered alerts to try and troubleshoot where the code stops executing
(Note that I only snipped the code of only one select condition "Premium")

HTML

```
<tr>
  <td><b>Quotation Type:</b></td>
  <td colspan="5"><Select name="chkQuotetype" id="chkQuotetype" onChange="fieldcheck();"><option value="" selected></option><option value="Premium">Premium</option><option value="Lite">Lite</option><option value="Bureau">Bureau</option></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><b>Switch Capture ?</b></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" id"chkswitchcap" value="0" name="chkswitchcap" onChange="check();" >
 </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript funtion

```
function check() {
    if (ContractType == "Premium") {
        QuoteType = "Premium";
        alert("code executed up to this point"); ** // Also tried if (document.getElementById("chkswitchcap").checked)**
        if (document.getElementById("chkswitchcap").checked == true) {
            alert("Yes checked if");
            Upfront = 2000;
        } else {
            Upfront = 10550;
            alert("No if failed");
        }
        BaseTotal = 1300;
        Add_medprax = QtyDirectories * 105;
        Add_support = QtyDirectories * 237.50;
        FSwitch = Switch * 4.80;
        OTotal = Upfront + Add_upfront + TTAddTotal + SMS;
        MTotal = Add_support + Add_directories + Add_medprax + Add_users +
            Add_storage + MMAddTotal + BaseTotal + FSwitch;
        OVat = OTotal / 100 * 14;
        MVat = MTotal / 100 * 14;
        GTotal = Total + Vat;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the second condition is failing, then `document.getElementById("chkswitchcap").checked` *must* be falsey. Have you verified exactly what the value is? Also note that the `== true` is redundant. It can be removed.

Comment: *"I have entered alerts to try and troubleshoot where the code stops executing"* Don't stumble around in the dark with an `alert` torch. **Turn on the lights** by using the powerful debugger built into your browser. :-) It will tell you that `document.getElementById("chkswitchcap").checked == true` is failing (causing a `TypeError`) because `document.getElementById("chkswitchcap")` is returning `null` because you have no element with that `id` (because you've missed out the `=` on the `id` attribute in the HTML).

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the `=` at `id"chkswitchcap"` in `<input type="checkbox" id"chkswitchcap" value="0" name="chkswitchcap" onChange="check();" >`

Comment: WOW, how did I miss that ? ... Thanks !! @brk

Comment: Typos don't need *answers*, just comments and close votes.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed  = in

```
<input type="checkbox" id"chkswitchcap" value="0" name="chkswitchcap" onChange="check();" >
```

while giving id

Comment: Typos don't need *answers*, just comments and (when you can) close votes.